# How to fix mongoengine dereference error after the migration to 0.8?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, flask, mongoengine

I've just upgraded mongoengine and now I'm getting an error. Currently, models have been defined as following:

```
class Descriptor(Document):
    root = ReferenceField(DescriptorNode, required=True)
    (..)

class DescriptorNode(Document):
    channel = ReferenceField(Channel, required=True)
    (..)

class Channel(Document):
    (..)
```

Using `DBRef = True`, this is the current code I used with mongoengine==0.7.10:

```
descriptor =  Descriptor.objects.get(id = xxxx)
channel = descriptor.root.channel
```

I've chosen to remove `DBRef = True` so as to migrate to mongoengine==0.8.1 and then rebuild the database.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
channel = descriptor.root.channel
AttributeError: channel
/site-packages/bson/dbref.py Line:88
```

I tried `select_related()`, but nothing seems to work properly.

*Descriptor*:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ae3f6ba2aa1c0a32998952"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2013-06-04T19:26:35.630Z"),
    "modified_date" : ISODate("2013-06-05T12:45:55.570Z"),
    "sequence" : 843174,
    "groups" : [ ],
    "name" : "desktop-BR",
    "root" : ObjectId("51ae3f6ba2aa1c0a329988b0"),
    "tree_hash" : "97e3716db74543e66a11405e9e04185452183ac1"
}
```

*DescriptorNode*:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ae3f6aa2aa1c0a3299885a"),
    "channel" : ObjectId("51ae0f06a2aa1c0a327f3958"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2013-06-04T19:26:34.235Z"),
    "groups" : [ ],
    "is_prioritized" : false,
    "is_published" : true,
    "modified_date" : ISODate("2013-06-05T12:46:02.704Z"),
    "order" : 0,
    "sequence" : 842926
}
```

Comment: Can you add here whole code of the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do as similar as example?

Firstly, to change `DBRef = True` to `DBRef = False`.
Secondly, to migrate by hands:

> ```
> for d in Descriptor.objects():
>     d.root = d.root
>     d.save()
>
> for d in DescriptorNode.objects():
>     d.channel = d.channel
>     d.save()
> ```

Comment: I think this will work. I had similar issues when accessing data created under 0.7 using 0.8. Since I was in the development stage I could just delete all data and build from scratch, but I think re-setting  the ReferenceFields like you propose in the example should work just fine.

Comment: There isn't any difference. `DBRef` is `False` by default

Answer (score 2):

Hi there is a migration in the [upgrade docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#referencefield) but this should work:

```
for d in Descriptor.objects():
    d._mark_as_changed('root')
    d.save()

for d in DescriptorNode.objects():
    d._mark_as_changed('channel')
    d.save()
```

Comment: dbref=False is now the default - so no need to declare it as False.